# Strange Equation in Json file

Tags: json, equation, algebra

I've found a json piece in an web application. There is this strange function with an equation that i cant figure out how it works.
Can someone tell me what the piece "challenge" is doing and how it works.

Here the full json code that i have.

```
{"twoFactorAuth":false,"namerator":false,"participantId":false,"smartPractice":false,"challenge":"decode.call(this, 'hFBCiPTDOn911QWsqXFdcTvJ5WIso6SzUTKgHg7ksdveJxixoNCOW6WofIVorPmfYYv6XuCIGnGjoJK6cneXzXdWfCY3TCc80E5V'); function decode(message) {var offset = ((70 \t *\t 76)   +\t 26) \t *\t (61   +\t 63); if(\t this . angular \t . isString ( \t offset))\t console .log\t (\"Offset derived as: {\", offset, \"}\"); return    _   .   replace \t ( message,/./g, function(char, position) {return String.fromCharCode((((char.charCodeAt(0)*position)+ offset ) % 77) + 48);});}"}
```

Comment: I think this has nothing directly to do with JSON. It is just a string, which is associated with the key "challange". Yes, and this string is JavaScript. It is some piece of code which (if executed) needs some time to calculate the result. This is the challange for a client. It probably should prevent for brute-force attacks or at least, it should slow them down.

Answer (score 0):

I see they are providing an encoded key along with a method to decode it for end users.

Its like a helper function to avoid confusion on how to decode the key.